# Can pyinstaller generated binary look to dl table?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have generated (on a ubuntu machine) a binary for my python 2.7 library. It works well, but  there are two things I don't like or don't understand:

1. Pyinstaller includes tons of system dynamic libraries that can be removed (lib*.so*) because it only needs (in my case) libpython2.7.so.1.0
2. Ok, I manually delete them, I don't care anymore, but why if I delete libpython2.7.so.1.0 executable doesn't look for dynamic library on system using dl table? Its there!!

To do this is for build a DEB package that requires dependencies using a control file, not include inside package duplicated system libraries.